# Dataproc cannot unzip .gz file zipped by AWS Kinesis

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

My company is trying to migrate services from AWS to GCP. We face some problems. The data collect by AWS Kinesis are `.gz` files. We use GCP's Cloud Storage to transfer these files to GCP platform and use Dataproc to process these data. All these data can be processed correctly in AWS, but cannot be read by the same Spark job correctly.

See thrown exception at the end.

I tried to unzip one of these files, like `ABC.gz`, in GCP Cloud Shell. The unzipped file still ends with `.gz`: `ABC.gz`. I think this is the root cause, as the Spark may tried to unzip the unzipped file.

If we rename these files by removing the `.gz` suffixes then Spark can run normally. However the renaming process is too time consuming and takes more than several hours to process one day's data.

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:225)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:111)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:182)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:218)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:176)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:151)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:191)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:50)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:190)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
 Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$12$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:6
31)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
```

Comment: Where do you store `.gz` files that you are processing? On Google Cloud Storage? If so, then how are you creating them? Please share command and/or code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further details it's hard to say what's exactly happening, but most probably you store `.gz` files uncompressed or using [GCS decompressive transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding). This means that files read by Spark already decompressed (they weren't compressed in the first place or were decompressed by HTTP client library if GCS decompressive transcoding is used) which causes failure because Hadoop/Spark will automatically try to decompress files with `.gz` extension too.

If above is true, seems that you don't have any other option except of renaming these files to remove `.gz` extension. Also, note that processing of Gzip compressed files is inefficient in Spark/Hadoop because they are not splittable.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to headers written with the object by Kinesis. Kinesis adds the `Content-Encoding=gzip` metadata to the object, which is added to the response header when the object is requested by the transfer, which causes automatically decompression of the object when it's transferred.

You can remove this header or remove the extension after download.

I believe that, if you use PowerShell with the AWS SDK to download the file, then it wouldn't decompress the file automatically.

Comment: Setting the value to utf-8 worked for me on JSON files! Note you can do this via `gsutil setmeta`: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit